# $f \in L^1$ and $f$ uniformly continous on $\mathbb{R}$ implies $f$ has compact support?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Is it true that if $f \in L^1$ and $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ has compact support?

Comment: Certainly not. Consider something like $\exp(-|x|)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ that goes to zero at $\pm\infty$ is uniformly continuous.